# No encuentro el JAVA CLASS en NETBEANS

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

AL momento de crear el proyecto ingrese a JAVA WITH ANT y luego JAVA APPLICATION , cree el JFRAME   y quería crear un JAVACLASS  y no lo encuentro

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega más información, no sabemos que estas realizando, agrega el código, revisar [ask],

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Ya intentaste darle click en el botón con icono de martillo y revisar en la carpeta dist o build?